# Three.js webglrenderer.render issue

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, nuxt.js, webgl

I'm developing a site with three.js and Nuxt.js.
When i try to use the EffectComposer, the console give me a lot of warnings like this:

`three.webglrenderer.render(): the rendertarget argument has been removed. use .setrendertarget() instead.`

In my case, I understand that it's an issue with the newest versions of three.js, because if I use an earlier version of three.js(101) it's works, but if I use the newest, I don't know what I need to change.

This is part of code in the constructor:

```
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    this.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x101010 );

    this.composer = new EffectComposer(this.renderer);
    this.renderPass = new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.composer.addPass(this.renderPass);
```

And this in the render function:

```
    this.counter += 0.01;
    this.customPass.uniforms["amount"].value = this.counter;
  
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    this.composer.render();
```

Thanks

Comment: Please ensure to update all parts of the library to the same version. Meaning files like `EffectComposer` or `RenderPass` should match with the `three.js` core file. The change you are referring to was introduced with `r102` and is mentioned in the migration guide: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r101--r102

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for the response. In the case of three.js I have the last version ("^0.130.1") and I have read than in this version the postprocesing is included, but when I try to import it, the nuxt.js console say me `Must use import to load ES Module` for this reason I have installed a npm package with the effect composer. How I need to import it to have the last versions of all of them?

Comment: All example classes are part of the `three` npm package. There is no need to install third-party packages. I suggest you read the following guide for more information: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation. Especially the `Examples` section.

Comment: Sorry for insist in this topic, but if I use the import like in the examples, it says to me `Must use import to load ES Module` and if i remove the type: module, says to me `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: @Mugen87 only for clarify I'm using the nmp module to install three.js. If I try to import the EffectComposer like a js file it says me `Must use import to load ES Module`

Comment: Sorry but it is not possible to provide more feedback without seeing your entire code. Better to make a new question for this.

Comment: @Mugen87 thanks for your time. I have solved it updating the version of threejs and modifying the nuxt.js configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarify this question, at the beginning, the error was that I was taking the postprocessing libraries from a non official npm and they had different versions. When I solved this problem, another appear, It was that it gives me this error when I tried to load the examples in my Nuxt code `Must use import to load ES Module`

After search, I have discovered that the way to load this kind of files it's include this little code inside the nuxt.config.js

`build: { transpile: [ 'three' ], }`